# Change color of table cell in javascript based on other cell's value

Tags: javascript, csv, html-table, background-color

I am displaying a table on the webpage as follows:

```
ID  | Val      | Num
ABC | Value1   | 1
ABC | Value1   | 0.8
CDB | Value 2  | 0.5
```

I want that if the cell value in `Num` column for that row is between 1 and 0.8, then the background color of the corresponding `Val` column's cell should be `red`, if between 0.7 to 0.5 then `orange`, and below it `yellow`.

I'm using `DataTables`

Below is my `js` code:

```
for (col_id = 0; col_id < csv_data[row_id].length; col_id++) {
          if (col_id === 2) {

              row_html += "<td>" + parseFloat(csv_data[row_id][col_id]) + "</td>";
          }
          else {
              row_html += "<td>" + csv_data[row_id][col_id] + "</td>";
          }
            }

            row_html += "</tr>";
            $('#' + el + '-table tbody').append(row_html);
          }

          $('#' + el + '-table').DataTable(datatables_options);
```

I tried to add the background color to the cell using the `style.backgroundColor` but I don't think it's working. I added this inside the for loop:

```
if (col_id === 1) {
              if (parseFloat(csv_data[row_id][2]) <= 1 && parseFloat(csv_data[row_id][2]) > 0.7)
              {
              row_html.style.backgroundColor = 'ec8e8e'
              }
          }
```

But it's not working. Could anybody tell me how to do it?? Thanks!

UPDATE:

My `csvToHtml.js` file:

```
var CsvToHtmlTable = CsvToHtmlTable || {};

CsvToHtmlTable = {
    init: function (options) {

      options = options || {};
      var csv_path = options.csv_path || "";
      var el = options.element || "table-container";
      var allow_download = options.allow_download || false;
      var csv_options = options.csv_options || {};
      var datatables_options = options.datatables_options || {};
      var custom_formatting = options.custom_formatting || [];

      $("#" + el).html("<table class='table table-striped table-condensed' id='" + el + "-table'></table>");

      $.when($.get(csv_path)).then(
        function(data){      
          var csv_data = $.csv.toArrays(data, csv_options);

          var table_head = "<thead><tr>";

          for (head_id = 0; head_id < csv_data[0].length; head_id++) { 
            table_head += "<th>" + csv_data[0][head_id] + "</th>";
          }

          table_head += "</tr></thead>";
          $('#' + el + '-table').append(table_head);
          $('#' + el + '-table').append("<tbody></tbody>");

          for (row_id = 1; row_id < csv_data.length; row_id++) { 
            var row_html = "<tr>";

            //takes in an array of column index and function pairs
            if (custom_formatting != []) {
              $.each(custom_formatting, function(i, v){
                var col_idx = v[0]
                var func = v[1];
                csv_data[row_id][col_idx]= func(csv_data[row_id][col_idx]);
              })
            }

              for (col_id = 0; col_id < csv_data[row_id].length; col_id++) {
          if (col_id === 2) {

              row_html += "<td>" + parseFloat(csv_data[row_id][col_id]) + "</td>";
          }
          else {
              row_html += "<td>" + csv_data[row_id][col_id] + "</td>";
          }


            }

            row_html += "</tr>";
            $('#' + el + '-table tbody').append(row_html);
          }

          $('#' + el + '-table').DataTable(datatables_options);

          if (allow_download)
            $("#" + el).append("<p><a class='btn btn-info' href='" + csv_path + "'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-download'></i> Download as CSV</a></p>");
        });
    }
}
```

My `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>CSV to HTML Table</title>



<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
   <h2>CSV to HTML Table</h2>

  <div id='table-container'></div>

</div><!-- /.container -->


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/csv_to_html_table.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function format_link(link){
    if (link)
      return "<a href='" + link + "' target='_blank'>" + link + "</a>";
    else
      return "";
  }
  CsvToHtmlTable.init({
    csv_path: 'data/fatty_acid_profiles.csv',
    element: 'table-container', 
    allow_download: true,
    csv_options: {separator: ','},
    datatables_options: {"paging": false},
    custom_formatting: [[2, format_link]]
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post your entire HTML and JS which you have tried so far or alternatively you can create JSFiddle.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM Updated the question and added my complete html and javascript files per your request.

Comment: @Xavier check below my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `append` row_html with `$(row_html)` and apply css to that with your condition.

Here `color` will be based on your condition.

```
 $('#' + el + '-table tbody').append($(row_html).css('background',color));
```

Check below sample to get more idea

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable();

  var val = 0.1;

  var row_html = "<tr>";
  row_html += "<td>ADD</td><td>val 4</td><td>" + val + "</td>";
  row_html += "</tr>";
  var color = "red"; // can be hex value, #ededed

  if (val > 0.7) {
    color = "orange";
  } else if (val < 0.4) {
    color = "yellow";
  }

  $('#example').append($(row_html).css("background-color", color));



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">


<body>
  <div class="container">

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable" id="example">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Val</th>
          <th>Num</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>ABC</td>
          <td>Value 1</td>
          <td>0.5</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>BBC</td>
          <td>Value 2</td>
          <td>0.8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>CBC</td>
          <td>Value 3</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Xavier Yes, you can. Mark as a answer if it helps you.